# Prove that $\{B_n\}$ is a sequence of mutually exclusive events

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $\mathcal{A}$=event space. Assume that $\{A_n\}$ is a monotone nondecreasing sequence of events in $\mathcal{A}$. Let $\{A_n\}$ be a sequence of sets defined as follows:
$$B_1=A_1; B_i=A_i-A_{i-1}~ \text{for}~ i\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}$$
Prove that $\{B_n\}$ is a sequence of mutually exclusive events in $\mathcal{A}$. Justify each line of proof.

I know that what I need to show here is $B_i \cap B_j=\emptyset$ for any $i<j$. I've divided it to be proof by cases where case $1$ is $i=1~\text{and}~j\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}$ and case $2$ is $i\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}$ and $j\in\{2,3,4,\dots\}$ where $i<j$ so that $B_i=A_i-A_{i-1} ~\text{and}~ B_j=A_j-A_{j-1}$ where $i\in\{2,3,4\dots\}$ and $j\in\{i+1,i+2,\dots\}$. I'm struggling with how to start out this proof, please let me know what my next step could be and if I made any error in my cases.

Comment: What is meant by "monotone nondecreasing sequence"?

Comment: @drhab it is said to be monotone nondecreasing iff $A_i \subset A_j$ for any $i<j$

Comment: I would rather call that a monotonically increasing sequence. The term "nondecreasing" is confusing. It could be interpreted as "not decreasing". If $A_1=\{1,2\}$, $A_2=\{1,3\}$ and $A_3=\{2,3\}$ then the sequence $A_1,A_2,A_3$ is not decreasing but also not increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is correct. As a first step, take an element $e\in B_j$. You have to prove that $e\not\in B_i$. For this, use the definition $B_j=A_j-A_{j-1}$. Since $e\in A_j-A_{j-1}$, what does this tell you about $e$?

Comment: how do I do this? I thought of using properties of subset since its a monotone increasing sequence but then remembered that they must be mutually exclusive.

Comment: I have added an extra hint.

Comment: I know this tells me that $e$ is in both $A_j$ and $A_{j-1}^C$ but how do I relate this with $B_i=A_i-A_{i-1}$? Sorry, I'm really just having trouble with this problem appreciate all your help!

Comment: This would also tell me that $e$ is not in $A_{j-1}$ which means that it can't be in $A_i$ since it's a subset of $A_{j-1}$ so as a result $e$ is not in $A_i-A_{i-1}$. Would that be correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

If $i<j$ then $B_i\subseteq A_i\subseteq A_{j-1}$ and $A_{j-1}\cap B_j=\varnothing$.